# How can I edit a GitHub release date?

Tags: git, github

I'm in the process of migrating some private repositories from another host to GitHub. Using a simple bash script and [`hub`](https://hub.github.com) I could easily automate converting all the old release texts (which were kept in a single markdown file) to GitHub releases.

However, whenever I use `hub release create` or create a new release from the website, the date does not correspond to the tag. It uses the current timestamp as release date. How can I edit this date to match the tag?

The [releases API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/) seem to show a `published_at` field, but I can't find any references to editing it. It only appears in the response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Release date is just when you create the release. You cannot edit it.